# php $_GET passing variables from one page to another

Tags: php, variables, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass my variables from one page to another, I'm using `$_GET` and it's grabbing my variables but on the same page instead of a new one, is it possible to pass them to a new page using `$_GET` or do I have to do another method, I've seen this done on the site using javascript asp and jquery but cant seem to find one with PHP that is explaining things very well.

this is what I have, other then this I'm pretty clueless on how to make this happen.

```
foreach($obj->jigsawes as $jigsaw):

   if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']==''.$query.'') {
echo "<a href='?p=$jigsaw_url'><img border=0 src='".$jigsaw->photo_url."'></a><br />";

echo "$jigsaw->name</ br>
 $jigsaw->address1<br />
 $jigsaw->phone<br />
 $jigsaw->city<br />
 $jigsaw->state<br />
 $jigsaw->zip<br />";


}else{
$query = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], ENT_QUOTES);

echo "<div><a href='?$query'>$jigsaw->name</a></div>";
    }
endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use session variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: session variables is for temporary users or something to that nature from what I read right?

Comment: @NukleHead - Sessions are used for keeping any sort of state across requests in a web application. It is especially useful for keeping authentication state. It is also advantageous to investigate more persistent storage techniques, if you wish to keep session data beyond the scope of a given ... session.

Comment: I would not use session variables just for persisting query params between GET requests, unless the prettiness of URLs is a huge deal...and even then, i'd think twice.  Using sessions tends to make for oddness if you have more than one tab open on a given site, or if someone uses the Back button.  Tacking the current query string onto the URL is far less likely to cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the current $_GET variables in a string, e.g:

```
$query = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<a href='?$query'><img border=0 src='".$jigsaw->photo_url."'></a>";
```

Note the use of htmlspecialchars in case it contains any nasty characters (potential XSS vector.)

Since in this case you're just loading the same page, `href=""` should work just as well.

Comment: I wanted to try your code out because it looks easier to use then session, however when I try to add it to my code the page just refreshes, the get function no longer works. check my updated code to see what I did please. Thank you

Comment: @NukleHead: If you just go to `?param=whatever`, that *means* the same page.  Of course it's just going to refresh.  If you want to go to another page, you need to put some URL before the `?`.  :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a new query string out of your post vars and attach them to your links.
[http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) is helpful for this.